# Tensorflow object detection retraining, confidence score really low

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api, pre-trained-model

I am trying to retrain the tensorflow object detection model - faster r cnn ( pretrained on iNaturalist) data. However, after training for around 60k steps ( where the total loss stabilizes), if I run an evaluation the confidence scores of my detections are too low, of the order of e-5.

The original model has around 2k classes. I'm training on 4 classes - almost equal distribution, with around 900 samples. The data augmentation option is "random_horizontal_flip".

Should I be increasing the number of samples I have? Maybe have more augmentation options?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Edit:
Config file being used

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 4
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "faster_rcnn_resnet50"
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
        scales: 0.25
        scales: 0.5
        scales: 1.0
        scales: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.009999999776482582
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.699999988079071
    first_stage_max_proposals: 32
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
      }
    }
    second_stage_batch_size: 2
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 25
        max_total_detections: 25
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 1
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003000000142492354
          schedule {
            step: 3000000
            learning_rate: 2.9999999242136255e-05
          }
          schedule {
            step: 3500000
            learning_rate: 3.000000106112566e-06
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/vectorweb3/Documents/Development_Sandbox/Manya/experimental-scripts/models/research/oid/faster_rcnn_resnet50_fgvc_2018_07_19/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 100000
  freeze_variables: ".*FeatureExtractor*."
  load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: false
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/home/vectorweb3/Documents/Development_Sandbox/Manya/experimental-scripts/models/research/object_detection/data/mosquito_label_map.pbtxt"
  queue_capacity: 4
  min_after_dequeue: 2
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/vectorweb3/Documents/Development_Sandbox/Manya/training_input_output_models/set4/tf_records.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 40
  max_evals: 1
  metrics_set: "pascal_voc_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  min_score_threshold: 0.0
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/home/vectorweb3/Documents/Development_Sandbox/Manya/experimental-scripts/models/research/object_detection/data/mosquito_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/vectorweb3/Documents/Development_Sandbox/Manya/training_input_output_models/set4/tf_records.record"
  }
}
```

The original config file is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet50_fgvc.config). 
The main difference is in the following:

- number of classes : in the original case it's 2854, for my task it's just 4
- max number of detections: original case it's just 4, for my task it's 25

The training loss looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Could you please also provide the config file you used for training and maybe some graphs like loss and accuracy?

Comment: Edited in the main post! Thankyou!

Comment: what about your image size and size of object you are trying to detect in pixel?

Comment: Image size is 1900x1500 and the maximum size of the object is appx 300x300

Comment: are the bounding boxes accurate?  are the classes correct?

Comment: If I don't threshold the score, around 85% of the original bounding boxes are being predicted correctly. The class are incorrect though.

Comment: I noticed in `train_config` there is a field `freeze_variables` and it freezes all the weights in the feature extractor. You may try removing this line and change `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars` to `true`.  This way the model may better fit your dataset. You can also try using different pretrained checkpoints too. The `totalLoss` here is the validation loss and it seems normal though.

Comment: I mostly did that because my dataset is not that big (~900 samples). So I thought I'd freeze the weights of the feature extractor and just train classifier - since the categories are different.

Comment: But why would freezing the weights make sense here? I'd think because the weights of feature extractor are fixed, the features generated on your dataset may not be very distinguishable from each other and would lead to wrong classification results.  Also I'd say 900 samples with 4 classes should be reasonably enough if you also use the pretrained models. But yeah, I still would not understand why confidence score would be such low? Maybe those scores are not meant to be displayed as they are meaningless.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? i am facing the same problem while training with similar settings . Loss seems to be decreasing. but class scores are very low.